Optimization assistance for script to create events with colors
I have been learning a bunch and I am at a point where this script does all that it needs to do, but I'm not sure if it is optimal. This script creates calendar events with color customization.
In one sheet (help_sheet), I have the calendar_Id along with dropdowns to determine different colors for events that will be created. In another sheet (data_sheet), I have the data structured as:
column A Checkboxes
column B Type_Color
column C Title
column D Start Date
column E End Date
column H EventID
What are some ways to optimize? I have a feeling that the call to different colors is not optimized, but I have yet to learn how to do it. Is this where arrays and objects come in?
Thanks, folks!
function CreateSelectionToCalendar() {
  var sheetHelp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('help_sheet');
  var CalendarID = sheetHelp.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarID);

  var sheetData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data_sheet');
  var rows = sheetData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = rows.shift();
  
  rows.forEach(function(row, i) { 
    if(row[0]) {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
      var type = row[1]
      var title = row[2];
      var tstart = row[3];
      var tstop = row[4];
      var eventID = row[7];

      var fillPaleBlue = sheetHelp.getRange(2,1).getValue();
      var fillPaleGreen = sheetHelp.getRange(3,1).getValue();
      var fillMauve = sheetHelp.getRange(4,1).getValue();
      var fillPaleRed = sheetHelp.getRange(5,1).getValue();
      var fillYellow = sheetHelp.getRange(6,1).getValue();
      var fillOrange = sheetHelp.getRange(7,1).getValue();
      var fillCyan = sheetHelp.getRange(8,1).getValue();
      var fillGray = sheetHelp.getRange(9,1).getValue();
      var fillBlue = sheetHelp.getRange(10,1).getValue();
      var fillGreen = sheetHelp.getRange(11,1).getValue();
      var fillRed = sheetHelp.getRange(12,1).getValue();

      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop,);

      if (type === fillPaleBlue) {
        newEvent.setColor('1');
      } else if (type === fillPaleGreen) {
        newEvent.setColor('2');
      } else if (type === fillMauve) {
        newEvent.setColor('3');
      } else if (type === fillPaleRed) {
        newEvent.setColor('4');
      } else if (type === fillYellow) {
        newEvent.setColor('5');
      } else if (type === fillOrange) {
        newEvent.setColor('6');
      } else if (type === fillCyan) {
        newEvent.setColor('7');
      } else if (type === fillGray) {
        newEvent.setColor('8');
      } else if (type === fillBlue) {
        newEvent.setColor('9');
      } else if (type === fillGreen) {
        newEvent.setColor('10');
      } else if (type === fillRed) {
        newEvent.setColor('11');
      }
    }
  });
}


For us to better help you please provide minimal reproducible example

Hi cnavar. I have edited the script to remove descriptions. To my knowledge, it seems like it has reduced to createEvent() requirements aside from the color variables and logic. I'm wondering in what ways could the latter two be optimized, if any.

Can you possible share a sample sheet for me to better visualize the input and the expected output.

Thanks, cnavar. Here is an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14p9CWoMzGnH5f4R4OmhGmfAeVXpxasMXAL9Ty-cdCls

Thanks for your response! It appears that an answer has already been posted and it's working as expected. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Try it this way:
function CreateSelectionToCalendar() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const hsh = ss.getSheetByName('help_sheet');
  const CalendarID = hsh.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarID);
  const dsh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data_sheet');
  const rows = dsh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = rows.shift();
  rows.forEach(function (row, i) {
    if (row[0]) {
      let [, type, title, tstart, tstop, , , eventID] = row
      let [[fillPaleBlue], [fillPaleGreen], [fillMauve], [fillPaleRed], [fillYellow], [fillOrange], [fillCyan], [fillGray], [fillBlue], [fillGreen], [fillRed]] = hsh.getRange("A2:A12").getValues()
      let arr = [[fillPaleBlue], [fillPaleGreen], [fillMauve], [fillPaleRed], [fillYellow], [fillOrange], [fillCyan], [fillGray], [fillBlue], [fillGreen], [fillRed]].flat();
      let newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop);
      newEvent.setColor(arr.indexOf(type) + 1);
    }
  });
}


Much appreciated, Cooper! This is wonderful! I definitely need to learn more on arrays.
newEvent.setColor(arr.indexOf(type) + 1);
How does this incorporate the if(){} else logic?
